# Make A Link Opens In A New Tab in html

Tags: html

I am facing a problem in making the link open in new tab. Below is the scenario I am facing:
I have one page(tab1) which contains three links, when i click on first link a new tab(tab2) is opened now when I click second link instead of opening tab 3, tab 2 is overwritten. I came to know that by using ***target="_blank"*** I will be able to achieve the above, but not sure where to add it in below statement. Kindly let me know your suggestions:

```
 <actions>
<action caption='Hyperlink1' name='[Action1]'>
  <activation type='on-select' />
  <source dashboard='Dashboard 1' type='sheet' worksheet='Sheet 1' />
  <link caption='' expression='https://gist.wal-mart.com/views/US-WMT-WeeklyDepartmentDashboard/SiteSnapshot'  />

</action>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks like XML that is used as the data to generate your actual HTML; this may be done manually or via technologies like XML Transforms (XSLT). Look into what uses the data above that you would add the `target="_blank"` attribute to wherever you render the final HTML.

Comment: Yes you are correct, this is an xml. Actually its the source of a report which I have created using a reporting tool called tableau.Since I am new to this, I am unable to find the final HTML. It would be a great help,if you help me in finding the final html.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use target"=_blank" in a link

```
<a href="http://yourlink.com" target="_blank">Your Link Text</a>
```